# ModelForm is_valid() always return false during unit testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, validation, django-forms

I have a simple Django code.

there is my model and form in *models.py* file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

class SupplierForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
```

and there is my *test.py*:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mysite.myapp.models import Supplier, SupplierForm

class SupplierTest(TestCase):
    def test_supplier(self):
        supplier = Supplier(name="SomeSupplier")
        supplier_form = SupplierForm(instance = supplier)
        self.assertEquals(supplier_form.is_valid(), True)
```

When I start test through manage.py, **is_valid()** always returns False, but I expect True.

What the reasons for fail **is_valid()** in this case ?
I use Django 1.3.

Comment: did you print "supplier_form.errors"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All forms constructed without data are "invalid" because they have nothing to validate :-)  You need to supply valid input to form's constuctor:

```
supplier_form = SupplierForm({'name': 'NewSupplier'}, instance=supplier)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. p.s. I've just found another question on stackoverflow with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869791/django-modelform-fails-validation-with-no-errors