# Transform an unbound form to a bound one?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to have a bound form from an object to use the is_valid method. The reason is because I have some old data that I want the users to correct according to the new validation rules. Then, I want to reuse the code of the clean methods in my form.

I ended up serializing my response:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core.serializers import serialize

(...)

fields_dict = simplejson.loads(serialize('json', [obj]))[0]['fields']
form = forms.MyForm(fields_dict)
if form.is_valid
```

This works but it doesn't seem very Djangish. Also, it seems as a common problem so I was looking for a better way of doing this.

According to the documentation, translating data from an unbound form to a bound form is not meant to happen:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method
However, that would be the easiest solution for me.

Comment: Tell me if I got it right: You have old data somewhere and since this was saved, the validation rules changed. Now you want to use a ModelForm to re-validate the old data and display errors to the user?

Comment: Where is `obj` coming from? This will help in determining what's going on here.

Comment: Exactly @Penthi. I think oogles gave me what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is Django's `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` function that will convert your existing model instance into a dictionary of data suitable for binding to a `ModelForm`.

This would probably be more efficient, and definitely more "Djangish", than serialising and unserialising the object.

And if you also create the form with the `instance` keyword, it will know to update the existing record when saved.

So:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

...

fields_dict = model_to_dict(obj)
form = forms.MyForm(fields_dict, instance=obj)
```