# Django form returns is_valid() = False and no errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have simple view in django app, which I want to show only when one of the forms is valid. I have something like:

```
@login_required
@require_role('admin')
def new_package(request):
    invoicing_data_form = InvoicingDataForm(instance=request.user.account.company.invoicingdata)
    if invoicing_data_form.is_valid():
        # all here
        return HttpResponse('Form valid')
    else:
        logger.info("Form invalid")
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(invoicing_data_form.errors)
```

I always get log info message that form is invalid, however, I get nothing in

```
invoicing_data_form.errors
```

It is very strange, because I am validating this form in other view using user input data and it works just fine. Any idea?

EDIT:
Just for clarification.
I am not requesting any data from user in this form.
I am using this form to validate some model instance (this form is subclassing from ModelForm).

Comment: first of all, you need to check for form post.

Comment: Why? I am not sending any data via POST. I just want to validate form (ModelForm) using model instance.

Answer (score 23):

That's because you're not "feeding" your form.

Do this:

```
invoicing_data_form = InvoicingDataForm(instance=invoice, data=request.POST or None)
```

Comment: I've added this, but form is still invalid :(

Comment: yes but you should be able to inspect the errors now

Comment: you need to check request.POST, if it's empty replace it with something else. If there is no data, the form is unbound and there won't be any error showing.

Comment: Using data=request.POST or None will cause that invoicing_data_form.is_bound will always be False.
When I change it, for example to data={} then form is bound, but its not validating (because data dict is empty ;))

Comment: well I couldn't know without your edit. Anyway the answer remains the same, fill up data ;)

Comment: I ended up with something like:
invoicing_data_form = InvoicingDataForm(data=request.user.account.company.invoicingdata.__dict__, instance=request.user.account.company.invoicingdata)

Answer (score 11):

You have an unbound form.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms

> A Form instance is either bound to a set of data, or unbound.
>
> If it’s **bound** to a set of data, it’s capable of validating that data and rendering the form as HTML with the data displayed in the HTML.
>
> If it’s **unbound**, it cannot do validation (because there’s no data to validate!), but it can still render the blank form as HTML.
>
> To bind data to a form, **pass the data as a dictionary as the first parameter** to your Form class constructor:

```
invoicing_data_form = InvoicingDataForm(request.POST or None, instance=invoice)
```

Comment: In this view I want to only validate form, I am not requesting any data from user. Thats why I am providing object instance to the form (which is ModelForm class instance). Are you sure thats I need to provide data?
Even if so, when I added this, I am still getting form invalid message, and there is no errors at all

Answer (score 2):

If you're already giving request.POST to your form using `request.POST or None`, but it's still invalid without errors, check that there isn't any redirect going on. A redirect loses your POST data and your form will be invalid with no errors because it's unbound.

Comment: This answer helped me find my solution. In my case, I was overriding `def __init__(self, request):` in the form class to add widget/field attributes, but forgetting to pass the request through the super call `super(Form, self).__init__(request)`. Same idea, I was losing the request object prior to calling is_valid().

Answer (score 1):

I got this for `AuthenticationForm` which needs `AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST)` see [Using AuthenticationForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421200/using-authenticationform-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on the answer by [@yuji-tomita-tomita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28554511/494739)

I typically use a CBV approach in Django, and how I'm handling forms:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        # do things
```

Reading the source code I noticed that `self.get_form()` using `get_form_kwargs(self)` to populate the form with `request.POST`, thus getting bound to data. So if you're overloading it like I did:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    company = self.get_company()
    return {"company": company}
```

Make sure to call the `super()`, and it will finally work:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    company = self.get_company()
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({"company": company})
    return kwargs
```